# How do you get Eclipse Neon to add maven dependencies to a project build path?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm using a recent install of Eclipse Neon (Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)). It comes with Maven. I have a pom with three dependencies. I converted the project to a Maven project. When I look at the build path, I only see the JRE system library under libraries. If I go to Add Library -> Maven Managed Dependencies, I see "Use Maven project settings...". In Maven project settings, I see "Resolve dependencies from workspace projects" is checked. There are no Maven dependencies resolving in my code. Am I missing something? Why is Maven being ignored?

Comment: if you right click on the project-> configure build path->libraries, do you see jre alone or do you also see maven dependencies?

Comment: `Import` -> `Existing Maven Project`.  The build path etc will be automatically populated